# Thread joining problems

Tags: linux, multithreading, perl

am using Perl on a linux box and my memory usage is going up and up, I believe because of previously run threads that have not been killed/joined.
I think I need to somehow signal the thread(s) that have done/run to terminate, and then detach
it/them so that it/they will get cleaned up automatically giving me back memory...

I have tried return(); with $thr_List->join(); & $thr_List->detach(); but my gui doesn't show for ages with join, and the mem problem seems 
to be still there with the detach...  Any help...

```
$mw->repeat(100, sub { # shared var handler/pivoting-point !?

while (defined(my $command = $q->dequeue_nb())) { #???
# to update a statusbar's text
        $text->delete('0.0', "end");
        $text->insert('0.0', $command);
  $indicatorbar->value($val); # to update a ProgressBar's value to $val
  $mw->update();

    for ( @threadids ) { # @threadids is a shared array containing thread ids
    # that is to say I have got the info I wanted from a thread and pushed its id into the above @threadids array. 
    print "I want to now kill or join the thread with id:  $_\n";
        #$thrWithId->detach();
        #$thrWithId->join();
    # then delete that id from the array 
    # delete $threadids[elWithThatIdInIt];


    # as this seems to be in a repeat(100, sub... too, there are problems??!
    # locks maybe?!? 
    # for ( @threadids ) if its not empty?!?
        }
   } # end of while
}); # end of sub

# Some worker... that works with the above handler/piviot me thinks#???
async {
   for (;;) {
 sleep(0.1);
 $q->enqueue($StatusLabel);
   }
 }->detach();
```

I have uploaded my full code here (http://cid-99cdb89630050fff.office.live.com/browse.aspx/.Public) if needed, its in the Boxy.zip...

---

First sorry for replying here but I've lost my cookie that allows editing etc...

Thanks very much gangabass, that looks like great info, I will have to spend some time on it though, but at least it looks like others are asking the same questions...  I was worried I was making a total mess of things.

Thanks guys...

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you got the join working but it was very slow?

Threading in perl is not lightweight.  Creating and joining threads takes significant memory and time.
If your task allows, it is much better to keep threads running and give them additional work rather than ending them and starting new threads later.  [Thread::Queue](http://p3rl.org/Thread%3a%3aQueue) can help with this.  That said, unless you are on Windows, there is not a lot of point to doing that instead of forking and using [Parallel::ForkManager](http://p3rl.org/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager).

Comment: Without the join I can see my Gui update(show what it is pinging and percent done), but with it(the join) the gui doesn't show up until everything is done...

Comment: err, joining waits till the thread is done.  is that not what you want?  what is the thread doing and when do you expect it to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **use only one Worker thread and update GUI from it**. Other threads just process data from the queue and there is no need to terminate them.

See [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=401819) example for more info